# php - How to ignore the required or included files

Tags: php, include

Normally for the people who use MVC Frameworks in php they use headers and footers that are automatically included. Even normal coders, they include them, so that they don't have to copy them again and again. In my application, since it is obligatory(by the framework) for them to be included, there are always there. But I want to create a gallery for some pictures and the gallery doesn't need the headers and footers (kind of fullscreen). So how can i ignore in my codes already included files so that they will not appear? Thank you.

Comment: You don't ignore them, you implement logic to not include them.

Comment: write code to NOT include them. `if(!$do_not_load) { include('whatever.php'); }`

Comment: What framework are you using? Most of them provide solutions to that such as creating different custom "layouts" that wouldn't include such files.

Comment: Model - View - Controller. Own MVC Framework